MS Access Form Datasheet - Enable / Disable Totals Row Using VBA
I would like to be able to enable / disable the Datasheet Totals Row via vba.  It would seem to be a very simple and straightforward thing to do, but I don't believe the ability is currently exposed in the vba api.  I'd appreciate it if anyone has worked out a way to do this.
The reason that I want to do this is that I have found that the Totals Row slows down a form that uses a Dynaset recordsettype, but is very fast when using a snapshot recordsettype.  If my users want to see totals, I want to be able to switch to a Snapshot type and turn on Totals and then switch back to Dynaset and turn off totals when wanting to edit.
I know that it is possible to toggle the state of the Totals row by calling the following:
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "RecordsTotals"

I also know that it is possible to set the state of the Totals row on a TableDef or QueryDef by using an undocumented property as follows:
db.TableDefs("YourTableName").Properties("TotalsRow") = True / False

(Thanks to this link for this method https://www.isladogs.co.uk/totals-row-vba/index.html )
However, this property does not exist on the Form vba api.
I've tried all sorts of ways of doing this, including

trying to hold a state variable and keep track of all changes of state to "know" whether the Totals Row is visible or not
trying to count number of recordset and displayed rows
trying to determine whether datasheet form footer section was visible or not
trying to take a screenshot or otherwise scrape the datasheet image to determine if Totals row is shown

However, it is one of the few things in MS Access that I have not been able to find a satisfactory workaround for.
I'd appreciate it if anyone has worked out how to do this reliable could share their method.

I think Colin's article covers it all - methods as well as limitations.

Thanks to @Gustav for alerting me to your post.
As my article made clear, when the Total Row feature was added, The Access team didn't add a VBA approach to enable / disable the total rows in form VBA. 17 years on from 2007, they aren't going to do so now! However, the code I provided in my article using CommandBars does the job perfectly
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "RecordsTotals"

Indeed, I supplied an example app which shows this code in use in a datasheet form. NOTE: So I could include buttons on the datasheet, its actually a split form with the single record view hidden
So I'm not sure what functionality you want that I haven't provided. Feel free to email me using the link in my article if you need further help. We can always add further info to this thread later for the benefit of others.

Colin! Welcome. :-)  Very happy to see you on Stack Overflow.

Thanks for your post @Isladogs.  Yes, I found your original article to be very informative, and using the ExecuteMso "RecordsTotals" method to toggle totals is good.  However, I'm still surprised that there is no programmatic way of knowing that the starting state of the Totals Row is.  I work a lot with large datasheets and if you forget to turn off totals before refreshing the page, you can be in for a long wait.  My post was just a fishing expedition to see if anyone had actually worked out a novel way of determining Totals state (rather than simply toggling) in the intervening years.
